# How to setup my machine to run as a web proxy?

Tags: proxy

I am running ubuntu 13.04 and I want to set it up so that all the web traffic in the LAN  must go through my machine .

Comment: What do you want to do? Sniff the traffic? Install a filter on squid? Log all internet access? There are many reasons why one would set up a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be done by two steps:

1. You should use some proxy service installed to serve your clients.
   I recomend **Squid**, for more information to install and configure on site https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/squid.html.
2. You must configure your clients to use your Squid by configure their gateway IP (on IP configuration) directing to you machine.

**Any problems, please let us know.
Take care!**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure, all the machines use your proxy, and cannot connect directly, it needs to have 2 network interfaces. One connects to the router, the other one to a switch where all clients get connected to.
The interface to the router may be set to obtain the ip automatically.
The other interface you can set as 192.168.66.1 subnet 255.255.255.0 for example. The clients must have ips like 192.168.66.2-254, subnet 255.255.255.0 with no default gateway.
Or you set up an dhcp on the second interface.
Then you set up a proxy on this box (apt-get install squid), listening on port 3389 for example (default). All cliens must be configured to use this proxy now.

An easier solution would be to run ipcop which includes a proxy that can be setup as a "transparent proxy" easily.